# Stop external USB keyboard repeating key presses on Vista

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard

We have an infuriating problem with a (Vista/Dell) laptop. When an external (Logitech) USB keyboard is attached to it, it regularly starts repeating key presses. When the user recently deleted an Outlook message, it deleted them all! When typing a message, suddenly it will start repeating the last keypress about 30 times (it varies).

It's not a mechanical issue. We've switched the keyboard out four times. Even tried a brand new one one. Every time it's the same. Also, the keyboard works fine on other machines.

The problem doesn't arise when the laptop's own keyboard is used - even if the external USB keyboard is still attached.

I'm stumped? Any ideas. Not using an external keyboard isn't an option due to our health and safety policy (...don't ask...).

Comment: I've been having the same problems ever since I upgrade from Win XP to Win 7. I've been using the same hardware for 2 years on XP, but once upgraded to Win 7 the same issues you described randomly happens. 

Not sure if it helps, but my mouse would occasionally freeze as well. I swapped out just the mouse, and both the mouse and keyboard issues (so far) have disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh... I've been through this with my Latitude D620 and my D630-derived Precision.  In my case it is due to the PR01X port replicator and having the USB keyboard and USB Mouse (it judders) connected directly to the replicator.  As a workaround plug the keyboard+mouse straight in to the USB on the side of the laptop.

For reference both the A02 versions of the replicator have this issue but an A00 one I have does not.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes. This was sort of the issue. The keyboard was connected through  a Belkin USB (2.0) hub (powered). After connecting the keyboard directly to the laptop, the problem disappeared.

Comment: dommer, do you have any docking stations? If so have you seen the same behaviour if the keyboard is plugged straight in to the docking station?  

I find the same happens, possibly as the dock is also a USB hub.  It's a major PITA and like you say only happens under Vista / Server 2008

Comment: @JoelMansford Thanks. This helped me fix a problem I have with Linux. http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=191&t=100874

Answer (score 2):

Is it a wireless external keyboard? I have the same problem with my Logitech wireless external keyboard and it's because it loses wireless connectivity with the base randomly.

Refer to the following link:
http://forums.logitech.com/logitech/board/message?board.id=software&message.id=3745

One workaround for you to try is to tweak the key repeat delay and repeat rate in Control Panel > Keyboard, or disable key repeat entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it was happening in your case as you seem to have independently verified the issue, just mentioning it here as a pointer for future people searching with a similar problem.

The only times I've ran into this same issue, it was because something was leaning on the delete button on one of the keyboards and the user didn't realize it - seriously.  I've seen the same problem with the Enter key on external keyboards because of similar issues and due to it's location on the numeric keypad.  The delete issue is more common with people on laptops, again due to key positioning, especially if a lead or something gets caught when closing a laptop lid in an external keyboard, monitor, mouse set up.

Despite it being such an obvious cause, you'd be surprised at the calibre of people that I've seen it catch out...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the logitech driver?   Have you updated it to the latest version?  Try it without any driver at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be something weird in some Dell USB keyboard handlers.  The reason why I say this is that we have 6 or 7 Dell laptops, all Latitude D820/D830s, and they all exhibit a similar problem.  In our case it is usually only the <kbd>Windows</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys which get stuck, which means you can be typing away and all of a sudden your windows all minimize, an explorer pops up, etc.  This is with multiple vendors keyboards: Microsoft, Dell, Logitech, and Ben-Q.

I don't know what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

We used to get a similar issue using PS2 keyboards via a PS2 to USB dongle with DELL desktops. Ocassional dropping of key strokes and ocassional repetition of a single key. The problem went away when we got rid of the PS2 to USB dongle and went with straight USB keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is a dell issue.  I've seen on the  810, 820,and some 830's Since a reboot usually fixes the problems the users complaints go away since they can do that themselves.  It stinks but all dell ever does it run diagnostics and say its ok.  The only answer I can think of it to get another vendor to let you use a laptop for testing purposes and if it can be shown it's the laptop, get management to buy from another vendor.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard was previously plugged into a Dell docking station.  Plugging the keyboard into a usb port on the laptop solved the issue.